# basic_digest authentication on Rest Assured

Tags: rest, authentication, rest-assured, digest, digest-authentication

I am getting trouble to get data using rest assured. to get data, I need to authenticate using basic_digest. to get authentication, I am using two Http request. the first one is for login and the second one is to get data. here is my code :

```
try {
       //my first http request
       response = given().auth().digest("id","pass").
       when().get("http://localhost:8080/login").
       then().statusCode(200).extract().response();

       ////my second http request
       response = given().
               when().get("http://localhost:8080/getToken").
               then().statusCode(200).body("access_token","token")
               .extract().response();

   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I dont know why, I always getting error on second http request (first http request is fine) "full authentication is required to access this resource". it seems the digest auth on first http request does not affect the second http request. how should I do to resolve the issue? when I try to create it on Jmeter, it is working well.

Comment: How are you authenticating the second request?

Comment: I add auth().digest("id","pass") on second request but it is still not working. copying session Id and add cookies still can't help me

Answer (score 0):

Typically basic authentication and digest authentication are performed in every request and thus you should provide the authentication details with every request. Rest Assured allows you to define [re-usable specifications](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#specification-re-use) or defining the authentication details statically so that you don't need to duplicate them for every request manually. For example:

```
RestAssured.authentication = digest("id", "pass");
```